# Declared the Properties files and initialized the Webdriver object in a class. I want to use this Webdriver object in the same package or another

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have declared the Properties files and initialized the Webdriver object in a class. And now I want to use this Webdriver object any where in the same package or another. How?

Please find the code below:

```
public class Config
{
public static Properties config =null;
public static Properties OR = null;
public static WebDriver driver = null ;
public static Logger APPLICATION_LOGS = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void initialization() throws IOException
{
    // creating properties files storing the ID's and xpaths
    APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Starting the test suite");
    APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Loading config files");
    config = new Properties();
    //FileInputStream fp = new FileInputStream("./config.properties");
    FileInputStream fp = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\ode\\utility\\config.properties");
    config.load(fp);
    APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Loading Object XPATHS");
    OR = new Properties();
    //FileInputStream fp1 = new FileInputStream("./OR.properties");
    FileInputStream fp1 = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\ode\\utility\\OR.properties");
    OR.load(fp1);

    APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Starting the driver");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    driver.get(config.getProperty("Testwebsite"));
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
}
```

I don't know how to use this... Help me out in this issue...

Help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

As you will probably use the driver in different classes in same and in different packages, How about initializing the driver in a class, and whichever class needs the driver, just extend the class so that when a test case run accesses the different methods from different classes, the same driver reference would be used there?

```
public class A {

public static WebDriver driver = new ......();

}

public class B extends A {
  //members and attributes of class B
}

public class C extends A {
  //members and attributes of class C

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the test framework I am developing, is I have created base classes:

BasePage.java
BaseTest.java
BaseElement.java

and initializing the webdriver object in BaseTest class. I am following the PageObject pattern. So any pageobject class that I create, I extend the BasePage class in it. Any test class that I write (TestNG test-methods with annotations), I extend the BaseTest class. Hence the driver object initialized in your BaseTest class can be passed around in your sub-classes as well as in your PageObject classes through their constructors. That will work.